# get row cell value from jquery mobile on tabhold

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am creating a Jquery Mobile Table and want get select row's cell value 
and right now i am create a static table but in render time there is another field.

```
<b class="ui-table-cell-label">-table header name - </b>
```

My static table is

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Single</th>
<td>2000</td>
<td>1800</td>
<td>10%</td>
<td><a href="">74/100</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Double</th>
<td>3000</td>
<td>2700</td>
<td>10%</td>
<td><a href="">64/100</a></td>
</tr>
</body>
```

And after render with Mobile Jquery

```
<tbody>
                        <tr class="canedit">
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Room Type</b>Single</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Rack Rate</b>2000</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Publish Rate</b>1800</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Discount</b>10%</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Avaliable Room</b><a href="" class="ui-link">74/100</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="canedit">
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Room Type</b>Double</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Rack Rate</b>3000</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Publish Rate</b>2700</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Discount</b>10%</td>
                            <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Avaliable Room</b><a href="" class="ui-link">64/100</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

so when i want get row cell value using this code

```
$(function () {
                $("tr.canedit").bind("taphold", tapHandler);

                function tapHandler(event) {
                    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
                    alert(customerId);
                }
            });
```

i get this as alert

```
<b class="ui-table-cell-label">Rack Rate</b>2000
```

i want only value

please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Use .text() instead of .html():

```
var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
```

API Doc: http://api.jquery.com/text/

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.